# Assigning to a class attribute from a method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the Michael Hartl rails tutorial. Struggling to get the remember token tests to pass, specifically, the test for non-blankness of the remember token.

The code for the User class is below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { :create_remember_token }


  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  private
    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

and the test I can't get to pass:

```
subject { @user }
  ...
  describe "remember token" do
    before { @user.save }
    its (:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
  end
```

and the error message I get is:

```
.....................F

Failures:

  1) User remember token remember_token 
     Failure/Error: its (:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
       expected blank? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:120:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.68878 seconds
22 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:120 # User remember token remember_token
```

I don't know if this is relevant but sublime_text isn't doing anything with the self keyword (ie its not highlighting it in a different colour).

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: hard to say. please post the output of log/test.log when running `rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:120`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're writing `before_save { :create_remember_token }` when you should have `before_save :create_remember_token`. The `{ }` is a block. Same as when you do

```
do
  #This is some code
end
```

That is also a block of code.
That's why your first before_save works, because you're giving the block a piece of code to execute. In the second before_save you're just giving it the name of the method to execute which has the block of code.

Tl:dr:
Change

```
before_save { :create_remember_token }
```

to

```
before_save :create_remember_token
```

and you should be good to go.